# How can I get transactions from a specified wallet, ethers.js, Alchemy websockets

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, ethereumjs

I can't get the transactions from a specific wallet provided, it's weird because I can get transactions filtering with the `to` argument and other arguments but when using `from` it doesn't. I don't understand why, wallet format and everything looks good. Any suggestion??
Here is the code: (changed the wallet cause I want to stream my own transactions)

```
const { Alchemy, Network, AlchemySubscription } = require("alchemy-sdk")
const {ethers, FixedNumber} = require("ethers")
const delay = require('delay')
require("dotenv").config()

const ARBI_WS_KEY = process.env.ARBI_WS_KEY

const settings = {
  apiKey: ARBI_WS_KEY, // Replace with your Alchemy API Key
  network: Network.ARB_MAINNET, // Replace with your network
}

const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings)

// Subscription for Alchemy's minedTransactions API
const add = async () => {
    let a = 0
    alchemy.ws.on(
        {
            method: AlchemySubscription.MINED_TRANSACTIONS,
        },
        (tx) => {
            let add0 = String(tx["transaction"]["from"])

            if( add0 == "0xc3EB0ad7d6bdB1Bd7E1fe9FDcf4C136c0Aedfac3"){ 
                console.log(tx["transaction"]["hash"])
            }
        }
    )
}


add()
```

Comment: is the address in the code (`0xc3EB0ad7d6bdB1Bd7E1fe9FDcf4C136c0Aedfac3`) the address that you're trying to get the transactions for?

Comment: Is an example address actually, I tried with others addresses but still its not working. Used also mine and did some simple transactions, wrap/unwrap eth, bought some token but I cant filter transactions using "from" argument. Really dont know what Im missing.

Comment: I'll try an answer which answers for the address above, and might be relevant to the others - lmk if I need to change something

Comment: Ok, Im agree with what you provided as an aswer. But I dont understand the last part. Let me put an example I have just tryed:

Used same code to try to get all hash transactions that come "from" this `0xfbB26A55a5757326368Ea292fe9678EafAE9970a`  address. And as you can see in the scan it did many movements like providing liquidity to the token just created in this hash https://arbiscan.io/tx/0xb5af5cbc631fa45c6cd234a5a6ae7a8b8b2188aad4289572f5a07af96055800d
But the code didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you suggesting with the last paragraph that this is not the way to get the transactions that this address has done then?

Comment: I'm saying that if you're looking at a contract, the contract will have never "done" the transaction - it will always be triggered by an EOA (non-contract account), and the EOA will be the one in the "from" field

Comment: I agree with that part, but still don't understand in this last example i provided in the comments why Im not getting the transactions from the address. the code looks clean and simple..

Comment: I see your point, I'll try to look into it more

Comment: I manage to understand what was going on. Wallet must be called in lower case using methods. Thats what I was missing!

Comment: As in, the address can't be checksummed (mix of upper and lowercase letters)?

Answer (score 0):

(**Clarification:** the OP has clarified in comments that the address in the snippet is an example, and that multiple addresses didn't work. I'm still posting this answer in the hopes that it might be relevant across all addresses the OP has tried, and also in the event that it helps others.)

Assuming the address and chain in the code above are the address/chain that you're trying to get transactions from, the reason is somewhat straightforward: the address you have in the code (`0xc3EB0ad7d6bdB1Bd7E1fe9FDcf4C136c0Aedfac3`) [is a contract on Arbitrum](https://arbiscan.io/address/0xc3EB0ad7d6bdB1Bd7E1fe9FDcf4C136c0Aedfac3). Let's explain this in a bit more detail:

The `from` field that you're talking about represents the EOA that initiates the transaction. (A useful way of looking at it is who's paying the gas.) A contract has no private key, and at least as of this writing, cannot initiate a transaction. As a result, there are no results when using this address and chain and searching for transactions from it. You can verify this quickly by looking at the Arbiscan link above - all the txs are marked `In`, none are `Out`.

The transactions you're getting returned with this address being `to` are the times other addresses are transacting with the contract. Whatever you're looking may be contained in these transactions.

For example, if you're looking for contracts this contract has called, these calls will (likely) be located in the traces of these transactions. You'd need a way of seeing all of the calls made during the transaction, though. I'm not sure you can get that through this particular API.